# Is there a natural number between $0$ and $1$?

Tags: logic, elementary-set-theory, natural-numbers

> Is there a natural number between $0$ and $1$?

A proof, s'il vous plaît, not your personal opinion. (Assume the Peano Postulates.)

Comment: Can't make a comment - but I would say this would depend on the ordering. Peano postulates don't define 1 either.

Comment: I suppose that with 1, Prof means S(0).

Comment: @Tim: No opinions, please! $$$$ :)

Comment: If there was a natural number between 0 and 1, what interesting consequences would there be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every natural number $m$ is either $0$ or $s(n)$, where $n$ is a natural number.

Proof: It can't be both, because $s(n)$ can't be $0$. Set of all natural numbers which are either $0$ or $s(n)$ for some $n$ satisfies induction principle, so it contains all natural numbers.

Direct consequence: Every natural number is either $0$, or $s(0)$ or $s(s(n))$ for some natural number $n$.

Suppose there is $m$ such that $0 < m < s(0)$. Either $m$ is $0$, $s(0)$ or $s(s(n))$. First two cannot hold, so you have $s(s(n)) < s(0)$, i.e., $s(n) < 0$.

Comment: How to prove that there are no natural numbers that are neither 0 or s(n)? Is the set defined so that "0 and S(n), and only those, are natural number"?

Comment: The set is defined A = {x : x = 0 or there exists natural n such that x=s(n)}. It is easy to prove it satisfies $0 \in A$ and $n \in A \implies s(n) \in A$. It follows that $A = \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Well, so s(n) < 0. Why not?

Comment: @Prof Duck: It depends on how you define "<". For example, $x<y$ could mean there exists $z$ that $x+z=y$ and $x \neq y$. If $s(n) < 0$ then there would be $z$ such that $s(n) + z = 0$, but $s(n) + z = s(n + z) = 0$, but 0 is not a successor.

Comment: What about nonstandard models?

Comment: Charles: The proof works for them too.

Comment: @Charles: Any nonstandard model of PA begins with a copy of the standard model. In fact it is enough for the model to satisfy just a certain finite number of axioms of PA to ensure this. The remainder of the model will look like some number of copies of $\mathbb{Z}$, which will themselves be densely ordered. But there is always a gap between any number and its successor.

Comment: @CarlMummert: I know the order type of nonstandard PA models, so I agree.  I just wasn't sure if the proof covered this.  (Despite sdcvvc's assertion, it's still not obvious to me that it does.)

Comment: @Charles: In any model, it is still true every natural is either $0$ or $s(n)$ (by induction for formula $\phi(n) = (n=0) \vee \exists m. n=s(m)$), remainder of the proof is unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT** $\rm\ \  S\:n\ =\ S\:0\ \Rightarrow\ n\: =\: 0\: \ne\: S\: m$

Answer (score -2):

One is defined as $\{\emptyset\}$. That a number n is between 0 and 1 means that $0\in n$ and $n\in 1$. Since $n\in 1$, it follows that $n=0$, a contradiction.

Comment: In Peano arithmetic $1$ is defined as $S(0)$. There is not even the notion of a set $\{\emptyset\}$, nor of the binary relation '$\in$'.