# Is there a mathematical proof that this number cannot be an integer?

Tags: real-analysis

I was just thinking about a certain problem that seems simple on the face of it but I am unable to prove it rigorously using mathematical proof. I have gone through the previous questions and this has not been asked before. Here is the question.

Suppose you have a number $\frac{a}{b}$ where a and b are positive integers greater than 0 and where a < b. This means that  $\frac{a}{b}$ is a fraction and it is not an integer. But is there any rigorous mathematical proof to prove that $\frac{a}{b}$ cannot be an integer or is it so trivial that a proof is not necessary?

Comment: $0 < \frac ab < 1$. Now see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/47385/42969

Comment: Choose the smallest integer strictly between 0 and 1. Now consider it's square...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the definition of rational numbers, two rational numbers $a/b$ and $c/d$ are equivalent iff $ad=bc$. Here the integer $a$ is equivalent(*) to $a/1$ as a rational number.

In your case, the question is whether  $a/b$ is equivalent to (an integer) $c/1$, i.e., $a=a1 = bc$.

Assume that $a,b,c>0$ are integers and $b>a$. Then $bc>a$ by monotonicity: $b>a$ implies $bc>ac$. Moreover, $c\geq 1$ implies $ac\geq a$. Thus by transitivity $bc >a$ and hence $a/b$ cannot be equivalent to $c/1$.

(*)The mapping $\Bbb Z\rightarrow\Bbb Q:a\mapsto a/1$ is a ring monomorphism.

Comment: That is an excellent proof.